# Drupal Video Search Functionality

Tags: drupal

Hello Drupal Community,

We have a video section on our home page and a search bar that should allow you to go to the normal drupal search results but ONLY return videos. Is there a way to hide articles that are not video articles and only display articles that are video articles?

Thank you all for any help you provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [custom search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search)
Or the [search configuration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config)